# Tagboxes or similar in JavaFX Textareas

Tags: java, javafx-2

In a Textarea, containing a boolean expression I want to mark individual terms using something similar to *tagboxes* (as for instance they are used here on stackoverflow to enter tags).

For instance, if the user enters a string, such as

```
A > 0 && B == 1
```

the terms A > 0 and B == 1, respectively, shall be encapsulated in a box.

My question only concerns the GUI-aspect. My question is *not* about how to parse the string.

Has anyone got an idea on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot achieve this with TextArea, but you could probably use [CodeAreaFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/CodeAreaFX)

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to your request.

TextAreas cannot have different styles applied to different text strings within the [TextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html).